# How to create a fabric object on the node server?

Tags: node.js, fabricjs2

I'm working on an application, in which user creates a series of canvases in their browser (using fabricjs for that purpose). The data are stored in a database, which then are planned to be used on the server side (nodejs) to generate PNG images of the canvases and then put them in a downloadable PDF file (I know I can do all this on the client side but the specificity of the app requires me to do this on the server).

The problem? Whenever I'm trying to create a fabric object in the node, I get the `Element is not defined` error. Here's a code sample:

```
function generatePdf(someVeryImportantData) {

    var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(null, { width: 300, height: 500});
    var text = new fabric.IText('Hello world');
                      //  ^ this is where the error occurs
    canvas.add(text); // <-- can't even reach that :-(
}
```

Node version: 8.11.2

Fabric version: 2.3.6

Tried downgrading node down to version 6, didn't help. It would be great if the solution worked both on client and server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `IText` has an external dependency: fonts. Those are included by default in the web browser, not so much in `nodejs`, where they should be supplied explicitly. Using simple objects like geometric shapes works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do HTML canvas on the server side, it is a HTML5 element.

The only way you can do this is to use a templating library, like [jade or the like](https://colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you sure about this? Such a use case is mentioned in the [official docs](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4#node). There are also [issues on github](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/4586) referencing this. Still, couldn't do anything studying those.

Comment: That example is using fabric.createCanvasForNode, then streaming it to file, which can then be served. That looks like it might work. You are using fabric.StaticCanvas, which looks like a front end function that is trying to grab an element from the DOM. In nodejs, there is no DOM.

Comment: Well, I've read some blog posts (for instance [here](http://promincproductions.com/blog/installing-fabricjs-for-nodejs-on-linux/)) about projects in which people actually do pull it off but due to proprietary nature of their code they're not really willing to disclose it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import fabric js this way

```
const fabric = require("fabric").fabric;
```